# MacOS: Monterey - Zsh using incorrect version

Tags: macos, path, homebrew, zsh

today I was looking to install some zsh themes/plugins that rely on newer versions of zsh. However when I checked my Zsh version it says

`zsh --version` returns `1.71.2 74b1f979648cc44d385a2286793c226e611f59e7 arm64`

so I installed a newer version with homebrew, however it looks like that's not being used as it still gives that as the version. When I run `which zsh` it returns `zsh: aliased to code ~/.zshrc`

`brew list zsh` returns `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zsh/5.9/bin/zsh`

`brew --version` is 3.6.3

Mac OS version is Monterey 12.6

I'm guessing I need to add something to my PATH but I'm not sure what and I can't find anything online that directly addresses the issue. Appreciate any help and let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: How did you check your Zsh version? Update your question.

Comment: Since Catalina, zsh has been the default shell on macOS, so you shouldn't need to install it via Homebrew. You can download the newest version (5.9) [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Arc/source.html)

Comment: @JoshFriedlander there isn't a way to tell my system to use the homebrew version? I already installed 5.9 with that and generally prefer managing/updating my installations with homebrew